# The type arguments for the method...cannot be inferred from the usage in view with html helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

This evening when I opened up Visual Studio 2013, this is what I'm seeing in my project. I tried rebuilding (scaffolding) the controller and views automagically. Even outside the helper, the model does not seem to contain any properties (using intellisense after .). Noticed, the ViewBag is also redlined. It's error is `One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found. Are you missing a reference?`

These problems really did pop up suddenly. I figured rebuilding the controller/views would fix it.

Oh, and I'm using MVC 5. Or, maybe 4.5. I thought I had 5, but the Web.config says:

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
```

[image]

Comment: One thing i can see, you are having `@model IEnumerable<Gators2.Models.InventoryItem>` in your view. So it's collection of InventoryItem. So you can not access it directly in `@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.variety.ItemId)`.

Comment: `targetFramework="4.5"` is the `.NET` version not the MVC version (and its fine). This can be caused by a mismatch of versions in you `web.config` files. Check your files for any possible mismatches - for example you might have `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.0.0.0`, but somewhere else it may be `System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.0.0`

Comment: It only shows up once in Web.config as `5.2.2.0`.

Comment: @RahulNikate It is in the `index.cshtml` view which takes a list -- it loops through the model creating a list of inventory items and adding links for the create, edit, details and delete methods. It's the standard index created when you create the controller automatically.